# How to display product sales per month in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I feel difficulties in this section.
so I plan to display product sales data A with the first month to the current period. where in each month it will display sales data.
However, here I find it difficult to display sales data. Also, the month that appears must be limited this month, so the coming months don't appear first.

This is my code

Controller :

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $thisYears = date('Y');
        $thisMonth = date('m');

        $produk = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $transaksi = Transaction::where('product_id', $produk->id)
                     ->where('created_at', 'LIKE','%'.$thisYears.'%')
                     // ->Where('status','!=','Menunggu')
                     ->get();
        $totalTrans = $transaksi->count();


        /*Date*/
        $months = array(1 => 'Januari '.$thisYears, 2 => 'Februari '.$thisYears, 3 => 'Maret '.$thisYears, 4 => 'April '.$thisYears, 5 => 'Mei '.$thisYears, 6 => 'Juni '.$thisYears, 7 => 'Juli '.$thisYears, 8 => 'Agustus '.$thisYears, 9 => 'September '.$thisYears, 10 => 'Oktober '.$thisYears, 11 => 'November '.$thisYears, 12 => 'Desember '.$thisYears);
        $transposed = array_slice($months, date('n'), 12, true) + array_slice($months, date('n'), true);
        $last8 = array_reverse(array_slice($transposed, -8, 12, true), true);
        return view('admin.product.insight.index', compact('transaksi','totalTrans','thisMonth','months','transposed','last8'));
    }
```

JS :

https://pastebin.com/cT8VMSy8

[image: image display product data sales]

Comment: Try to manipulate with date with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). It will be easier for you.
Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mare96 mentioned, try working with Carbon. Code is commented to explain what is being done.

```php
$data = [];

// Circle trough all 12 months
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    // Create a Carbon object from the current year and the current month (equals 2019-01-01 00:00:00)
    $date = Carbon::create(date('Y'), $month);

    // Make a copy of the start date and move to the end of the month (e.g. 2019-01-31 23:59:59)
    $date_end = $date->copy()->endOfMonth();

    $transaksi = Transaction::where('product_id', $produk->id)
        // the creation date must be between the start of the month and the end of the month
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $date_end)
        // ->Where('status','!=','Menunggu')
        ->count();

    // Save the count of transactions for the current month in the output array
    $data[$month] = $transaksi;
}
```

This will give you an array that should look like this, depending on your data:

```
array(12) {
  [1]=>int(254)
  [2]=>int(564)
  [3]=>int(345)
  [4]=>int(675)
  [5]=>int(234)
  [6]=>int(123)
  [7]=>int(143)
  [8]=>int(676)
  [9]=>int(787)
  [10]=>int(567)
  [11]=>int(780)
  [12]=>int(898)
}
```